# How many rectangles of different sizes can fit in a large rectangle, until you need to exchange the large rectangle for a bigger rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, packing-problem

I'm trying to figure out how to plan something without actually going out and buying the stuff.
the title is pretty much the problem, but let me give an example

let's say you have 2 rectangles of Length x Width: 24cm x 62cm, and 25cm x 62cm and you want to fit it in a single rectangle. and you have two larger rectangles that have LxW of 120cm x 60cm and 150cm x 90cm. is there a way I can check whether the two smaller rectangles will fit in the smaller of the two large rectangles before going with the larger of the two large rectangles?

Comment: Trial and error comes to mind. I would measure with a ruler and cut out a few paper rectangles of size 24mm x 62mm, and a few more of size 25mm x 62mm and see how many I can get into a paper rectangle of size 120mm x 60mm and  then compare with the 150mm x 90mm. This is more fun than a mathematical solution anyway.

Comment: The general problem that you describe is famous for **not** having a fast mathematical algorithm to solve it. It's basically trial and error.

Comment: With only two rectangles there are very few configurations to try.  Either one works or none do and you are done.  For larger numbers there are many configurations.  Often it is easy because you find the obvious solution or some simple thing says you can't.  Otherwise it is very hard.